# VBA get object type and library for LDAP

Tags: vba, ldap, typename, object-type

does anyone know a way simmilar to TypeName() to get the name of the object? For example:

```
Dim obj
Set obj = GetObject("ADODB.Connection")
Debug.Print ObjectType(obj)
```

I would like this to print out "ADODB.Connection" rather than "Object" like TypeName(). This is a simplified version of the problem, I would most likely do something like:

```
Dim obj
Set obj = GetObject("LDAP://" & DN)
Debug.Print ObjectType(obj)
```

the reason for all of this is so that i can get rid of all:

```
Dim a as object
```

Type of statement.

Comment: You want to get rid of `Dim a as Object` and replace it with something like `Dim a As ADODB.Connection` or `Dim a As Excel.Application`, etc.??

Comment: In my case I want to do <code>Dim a As LDAP</code> except I cannot find what the actual object type is.

Comment: Tried `TypeName(obj)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have moved on as this thread is old, but as someone who stumbled upon this while searching for and answer to the same question I figured I'd post an answer for the next person.

the reference you need to add is **Active DS Type Library** and if you are searching for user info the object type is ActiveDs.IADsUser.